# facebook link recognizer for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am developing an app that allows users to post to walls/groups very much like facebook or a classic forum. I really like the way you can post a link on facebook and the link will be recognized as a video, pic, or other media and will automatically display. Its a great feature b/c it keeps users on facebook instead of leaving the site. On that note, I was looking to implement something similar for my the app I am developing. Are there any rails plugins/gems that do this kind of thing?

Yes, I know how to google and have done so. I realize that I could write regular expressions to scan the link and then take an according action. However, I am looking for an existing implementation to save a boat load of time.

Any and all input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing implementations would probably be employing some form of regular expression, although another approach is using custom "Markdown" syntax or BB code to make the regular expression easier.